# Unknown string format. transforming a datetime python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following date column type object,i want to format it datetime
use:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'spanish_mexico')

df['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'], format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S') 



date

viernes 8  diciembre  2017 12:00:00 
2019-05-14 7:22:00
```

and get the error

```
ValueError: time data 'viernes 8  julio  2016 11:00:00 ' does not match format '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

How can I do the transformation to get

```
2017-12-08 12:00:00
2019-05-14 7:22:00
```

Comment: Use `strptime` but make sure your Python supports a Spanish language locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you supply a parsing directive to `pd.to_datetime` via the `format` kwarg, it has to *exactly match* the format in your date/time string including spaces etc. For the given example:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_MX.utf8') # on Ubuntu; just 'es_MX' on Windows

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'fecha': ['viernes| 8 de julio de 2016| 11:00:00 ()',
                             '2019-05-14 7:22:00']})

# clean date/time strings
df['fecha'] = (df['fecha'].str.replace('\||\(|\[|\&|\#|\]|\)|(de)', '', regex=True) # unwanted characters
                          .str.strip() # whitespaces at beginning and end
                          .str.replace(' +', ' ', regex=True)) # more than one space in sequence

# try to infer format first, works well for standard formats
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'], errors='coerce')

# where the conversion resulted in NaT (no value), use the excplicit format
m = df['datetime'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'][m], format="%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")

df['datetime']
0   2016-07-08 11:00:00
1   2019-05-14 07:22:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

See [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for an overview of available directives.

Comment: can you combine formats? that is, it works fine for where I have text but having combined format with "2019-05-14 7:22:00" does not match

Comment: @KLM right, I see you got that in your example. I've made an edit that offers a solution to that - do you have more different formats or just those two?

Comment: if I had it in this format "viernes| 8 de julio de 2016| 11:00:00 ()"
modifying your function "format="%A| %d  %B  %Y| %H:%M:%S()" leaves it in NaT

Comment: @KLM there seems to be a space missing; `%S ()` at the end. If you have many of such "dirty" date/time strings, you might be better off cleaning them first, before parsing to datetime. E.g. remove all parenthesis and brackets, replace multiple whitespace characters with a single space etc.

Comment: I already did it and it remains at the end as in the example I gave, your function works fine if I copy your df however with my data it leaves them in NaT

Comment: @KLM I've added an example what I mean by *string cleaning first*.

Comment: I already cleaned them and NaT continues to appear in the data as "viernes 8 julio 2016 11:00:00"

Comment: @KLM sorry but this is not reproducible from the example you provided. `strptime` does not do magic; there's either something wrong with your parsing directive or your input is different than shown. Furthermore, NaT is only inserted if you set `errors='coerce'`, otherwise an error will be raised.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the datetime module with the following documentation for the specified formats

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: It's 2021; probably finally update your bookmark to Python 3.

Comment: the datetime module and the behavior thats needed for this does not alter between python3 and 2